# How to draw an irregular line with photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, path, brush, pen-tool

I have a path, a simple semi-ellipse (not closed) similar to an oblong "C" I'm trying to turn it into a form with the following aspects:

1. the brush must be flat and not round, the extremities must end with a straight trait, like | and not rounded
2. I also want to make extremities wider and the middle thin

I have tried designing the irregular line with path but it is too small to work with and seems difficult to give the right size/curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with 3 shapes via the **Shape Tool**.

[image]
[image]

- Draw your first, outer **ellipse**
- Draw a second, smaller, inner **ellipse** to create the center cut out or counter. After you draw the second ellipse, change the **shape interaction** options in the** Control Bar** across the top of the screen to `Exclude Overlapping Shapes`. 
  [image]

  The center will be cut out of the larger ellipse. Reposition or transform the smaller ellipse path as needed.
- Draw a **rectangle** covering the portion you do not want visible. After you draw the rectangle, change the **shape interaction options** in the **Control Barr* to `Subtract Front Shape`. 
  [image]

This is all now a single shape layer. You can change the fill/stroke of the layer as you wish or otherwise transform it like you would any other shape layer.

If you need to further edit or refine the individual positions of the paths, use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to do that.

Alternatively, you can use the **Pen Tool** to just draw the overall shape....

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: wow amazing! What is the main difference between Exclude and Subtract from shapes?

Comment: I have followed the steps however the new shape handles are much bigger than its size, how can I have proper shape size that consider the effective width of the shape?