# How to remove exclusion shapes from main shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, path, mask

Following up this question solution, I have designed the elipses as intended. However I'm now stuck with a "masked" shape where I want to have only the elipses as the final shape:

[How to draw an irregular line with photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90962/how-to-draw-an-irregular-line-with-photoshop/90965#90965)

For instance the shape control box consider the whole thing also if the rectangle was intended to exclude from the other shape. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Here is a capture of what my test looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shape layer still selected, go back up to the **Path Operations** menu that you have been using to combine the shapes and select **Merge Shape Components** :

[image]

Done.

Comment: thank you! I'll check that out once I'll be back, I'm not sure it is available in CS4 but I might be wrong.